# Need to share record without manual sharing

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I have set of 5 custom object and one parent object for them.
suppose A is parent record and its child record of different object are B,C,D,E and F.
What i need is owner of record B can read/edit B but should have read only permission for C,D,E and F.
Similarly owner of C should have read/edit permission on C and read permission for B,D,E and F.

How to go for this scenario. Ready to create extra field if required to store owner or something else on parent or child objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **record types** to solve this. Then if the person needs to see only "object B", his profile would allow him to edit it, but only view the other ones. Likewise, other people would need different profiles to view/edit their objects.

But using this solution would require you to use the same custom object for every one of those (which depending on what you want might be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to keep it as 5 different custom objects, you will need apex trigger to populate owner fields to other records.Also will there be more than one record of one particular custom object under one parent.If yes it will create further complication as these records can have different owners. On top of these you will have to create sharing rules. It does not sound like a very good idea. Best way would be to use manual sharing and create sharing entries from trigger.